# Plot a graph for the data types of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I want to visualize the data types of my dataset as a part of exploratory data analysis and I have this data.

```
In [1]: df_planet = pd.DataFrame({'mass': [0.330, 4.87 , 5.97],
                                 'radius': [2439.7, 6051.8, 6378.1],
                                 'planet': ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth']})
In [2]: df_planet.dtypes
Out[2]: mass      float64
        radius    float64
        planet     object
        dtype: object
```

How can I create a **pie chart** for the datatypes of `df_planet` (i.e. ***66.67% float64*** and ***33.33% object***)?


I tried the following code but it throws an error:

```
In [3]: plt.pie(df_planet.dtypes, autopct='%.0f%%')
Out[3]: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'numpy.dtype[float64]'
```

Comment: [Tutorial...](https://www.w3schools.com/python/matplotlib_pie_charts.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count the data types.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_planet = pd.DataFrame({'mass': [0.330, 4.87 , 5.97],
                             'radius': [2439.7, 6051.8, 6378.1],
                             'planet': ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth']})


plt.pie(df_planet.dtypes.value_counts(),autopct='%.0f%%')

plt.show()
```